# if with multiple values (TSQL)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement

I'm newbie in SQL and i don't understand how this language work
I have a code:

```
if (select Zarobki from PRACOWNICY) < 3000
    update PRACOWNICY set Zarobki = Zarobki * 2
else
    update PRACOWNICY set Zarobki = Zarobki / 2
```

How I can compare multiple values form table? I think select work like loop statements

Comment: What is your RDBMS?

Comment: MS SQL Management Studio

Comment: Just curious what kind of logic is it? If someone earns let's say 2000 then after update  will get 4000, and person that has 5000 will get 2500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this kind of operation can be done with one query.

```
update PRACOWNICY 
set Zarobki = 
  case when Zarobki < 3000 then 
    Zarobki * 2 
  else 
    zarobki /2 
  end
```

This query is equivalent to

```
update PRACOWNICY set Zarobki = Zarobki * 2
where Zarobki < 3000;

update PRACOWNICY set Zarobki = Zarobki / 2
where Zarobki >= 3000;
```

Comment: yes because your example code has else statement :) what do you want to do? please update your question and provide sample data and expected output so that we can understand what you are up to

Comment: I modify your code and it work. Just change 'else' on second 'when -than'

Answer (score 5):

You can write:

```
update PRACOWNICY
set Zarobki = CASE
               when Zarobki < 3000
                then Zarobki * 2
               else
                then Zarobki / 2
              END
```